# C++ template class self referencing

Tags: c++, templates, self-reference

I am trying to create a class `Info<P,S>` which holds a pointer to another object of type `Info<S,P>`. I have the following code.

```
template <class P, class S>
class Info {
….
public:
Info(…, Info<S,P>* parentInfo) : …, parentInfo(parentInfo)
{}
…
private:
Info<S, P> *parentInfo;
};

….

typedef Info<ActualP, ActualS> OneInfo;
typedef Info<ActualS, ActualP> OtherInfo;
…
OtherInfo* parentInfo =…;
OneInfo info(…, parentInfo);
```

This is not compiling and saying the constructor is not a valid one (at the call).

I suppose this would cause an infinite recursion while trying to resolve. Am I right? What are the alternatives to implement this intent of referencing `Info<S,P>` from `Info<P,S>`?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Put it in another function instead of constructor.

Comment: @user1412084 please put the complete error message including the `candidates are` part into the original post.

Comment: @AtoMerZ Thanks. Adding a set function to set it instead of the constructor works. But Info is a class instantiated at many places. Adding it to constructor would mean I won't forget to set the parent at a few places.

Comment: @user1412084 Then you should use different parameters with you construtor. I'm guessing there are two fields `S` and `P` in you `Info` class. So you should try to call the constructor like this: `Info(S, P)`.

Comment: add another `ctor` that *zero-initializes* `Info<T1,T2>::parentInfo` that is used if you don't pass any parent.

Answer (score 1):

Use [typename](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/keyword_typename.htm) to refer a type that depends of a template parameter:

```
template <class T>
class Info
{
    public:
    Info() : parentInfo(NULL) {}

    Info(Info<typename T> *info) :
        parentInfo(info)
    {
    }

    private:
        Info<typename T> *parentInfo;
};

int _tmain(int, _TCHAR**)
{
    Info<int> parent;
    Info<int> child(&parent);
}
```